# "No logs found" in grafana

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I installed Loki, grafana and promtail and all three runing. on http://localhost:9080/targets Ready is True, but the logs are not displayed in Grafana and show in the explore section "No logs found"

promtail-local-config-yaml:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      host: ward_workstation
      agent: promtail
      __path__: D:/LOGs/*log
```

loki-local-config.yaml:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
```

How can  i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using Loki in Windows ?

In your promtail varlogs job ,the Path "D:/LOGs/*log" is obviously wrong, you cannot access the windows file from your docker directly.

You shoud mount your windows file to your docker like this:

```
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.5.0
    volumes:
      - D:/LOGs:/var/log
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
```

Then everything will be ok.

Note that, in your promtail docker the config is like this:
[image]

you can adjust both to make a match...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general advice how to debug *Loki* according to the question's title:

(1) Check promtail logs
If you discover such as `error sending batch` you need to fix your *Promtail* configuration.

```
level=warn ts=2022-10-12T16:26:20.667560426Z caller=client.go:369 component=client host=monitor:3100 msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 error="Post \"http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push\": dial tcp: lookup *Loki* on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host"
```

(2) Open the *Promtail* config page and check, if *Promtail* has read your given configuration: http://localhost:3101/config

(3) Open the *Promtail* targets page http://localhost:3101/targets and check

1. if your service is listed as *Ready*
2. if the log file contains the wanted contents and is readable by *Promtail*. If you're using docker or kubernetes I would log into the Promtail Container and would try to read the logfile manually.

To the specific problem of the questioner:

The questioner said, that the services are shown as READY in the targets page. So I recommend to check (1) Promtail configuration and (3b) access to log files (as Frank).